# Retlang: What is the best way to unsubscribe from a channel?

Tags: c#, retlang

I'm not sure what is the best way to unsubscribe from a channel when using Retlang.

When you subscribe by calling `ISubscriber<T>::Subscribe(...)` you are returned an `IUnsubscriber`. This interface has no methods.

Going up a level, `IChannel<T>` also does not have any methods.

The only thing I can think of is casting an `ISubscriber<T>` to the concrete `Channel<T>` and calling its `Unsubscribe()` method or adding an `Unsubscribe()` method to `ISubscriber<T>`.

I'm just curious if anyone knows what they had in mind before I modify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IUnsubscriber` interface implements `IDisposable`.  Just call `Dispose()` on the `IUnsubscriber` handle you receive, and it should unsubscribe itself.